# GhostScipt High CPU Usage

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am facing an issue of High CPU usage while compressing files. The scenario i have is a `.Net` `WebService`, that compresses PDF Documents with about 500kb.

I have a balanced two servers infrastructure, quad core with 8GB RAM, and a Round Robin load balancer in front of.

I've implemented firstly by launching the GS.exe, with the switches to compression, and seeing that the CPU usage is always at 100%, i´ve implemented in C# referencing the nuget Artifex GhostScript.Net with the same switches.

The Switches that i use are in both cases are:

```
sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-dBATCH
-dNOPAUSE
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook
-dAutoRotatePages=/None
-dPrinted=false
-dNOSUBSTDEVICECOLORS
-dDEVICEWIDTH=2479
-dDEVICEHEIGHT=3508
-dColorImageResolution=300
-dGrayImageResolution=300
-dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic
```

I've also played around with `dNumRenderingThreads`, without any success.

How can I optimize the CPU usage to present 100% consumption? Is there any switch? How to prevent this High CPU using `GhostScript` ?

I've already dig around, tried to use another libraries, however the do not compress well, and i am stuck it this CPU usage in `GhostScript`.

Any hint, help how to resolve this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework/nuget/library would you recommend for ? The PDF is generated from another software, due to is content i cannot share, however it is not compressed, that is why i have this requirement to implement.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't compress PDF files. It makes new files which may, or may not, be smaller depending on the user's choices. NumRenderingThreads only affects **rendering**; the clue is in the name, and creating a new PDF file doesn't render it (to an image). As for CPU usage; GS with the pdfwrite devcie will only use a single thread of execution, but it will, obviously, use as much of that CPU time as the OS makes available. I cannot see any way that it possibly uses more than a single core while executing So I don't really see why this is a problem, or what you think should be done about it.